# Pegar posição do celular. GPS

Tags: android

Eu tenho uma aplicação, onde eu preciso pegar as coordenadas de onde o celular está hora que eu abrir o formulario de cadastro e depois quando eu cadastras, para armazenar as 2 localizações. Como faço para pegar a localização do celular?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1. Defina no manifest que utilizará o GPS:**

```xml
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION">
```

**2. Crie um LocationManager**

```java
LocationManager gerenciadordeLugar = (LocationManager)   : getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
```

**3. Verifique se o GPS está ligado.**

**4. Implemente um Listener e pegue as coordenadas:**

```java
LocationListener meuListener = new MeuListener();
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 5000, 10, meuListener);
```

[Exemplo completo no gist](https://gist.github.com/mansueli/170381bce400bc221151)

Comment: No passo 3, verificar se o GPS está ligado, tenho que fazer isso manualmente?

Comment: Sim, e se olhar no código que postei no [gist](https://gist.github.com/kyllopardiun/170381bce400bc221151) verá que este código nessa parte: `flag = displayGpsStatus();`

Comment: E esse LocationListener é importado do android.location ou do com.google.android.gms.location?

Comment: E como vai ficar o listener?

Comment: @meisterx7  `import android.location.LocationListener;`. Por favor, veja o gist. Está tudo lá.

Comment: Amigo, por favor.. estou estudando o Android Studio e o GPS, mas esse codigo do gist esta OFF ?!?!   por favor teria um outro lugar pra eu consutar e  ver funcionando..    queria muito aprender isso! OBRIGADA!

Comment: @CamilaYamamoto troquei meu nome no github faz pouco tempo, esqueci que isso estava por lá. Obrigado por avisar ( arrumei o link)